# Delimiters in the \seq_set_split:Nnn function

Tags: expl3, latex3

Obviously, the `\seq_set_split:Nnn` function allows the delimiter to be used explicitly; for example the statement `\seq_set_split:Nnn \Args_seq {,} {x,y,z}` will put `x`, `y` and `z` into the first three locations in `\Args_seq`.

Or, wrapping this functionality into a `\NewDocumentCommand` the delimiter can be passed as a parameter, see for example `\myMacroA` in the MWE below, where in `\seq_set_split:Nnn \Args_seq #2 {#1}` parameter `#1` is split into `\Args_seq` using the delimiter specified in parameter `#2`.

However, in one of my gizmos I wanted to pop delimiters off a stack (implemented by an `L3seq` of course), store them in a `_tl` type variable and then use that variable in the `\seq_set_split` function. All attempts failed miserably; the `\myMacroB_Main` control sequence below illustrates the point. What type of variable does the delimiter require?

Much obliged, as usual.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%   --------------------
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%   --------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
\seq_new:N \Args_seq
\int_new:N \ItemCount_int
\int_new:N \index_i
\tl_new:N \aux_tl
\tl_new:N \sep_tl
%   --------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroA{O{}O{,}}{\myMacroA_Main:nn {#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Npn \myMacroA_Main:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_clear:N \Args_seq
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \Args_seq #2 {#1}
    \myShowArgs{\Args_seq}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroB{O{}O{,}}{\myMacroB_Main:nn {#1}{#2}}
\cs_new:Npn \myMacroB_Main:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_clear:N \Args_seq
    \tl_set:Nn \sep_tl {#2}
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \Args_seq \sep_tl {#1}  %does not accept the delimiter as a _tl variable.
    \myShowArgs{\Args_seq}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \myShowArgs #1
  {
    \tl_clear:N \aux_tl    
    \int_set:Nn \ItemCount_int {\seq_count:N #1}
    \int_set:Nn \index_i {1}
    \int_do_until:nNnn \index_i > \ItemCount_int
      {
        \tl_set:Nx \aux_tl {\seq_item:Nn #1 {\index_i}}
        \tl_use:N \aux_tl \text{~}
        \int_incr:N \index_i
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
1. \verb+\myMacroA[a,b,c,1,2,3]+\\
\myMacroA[a,b,c,1,2,3]

2. \verb+\myMacroA[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]+\\
\myMacroA[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]

3. \verb+\myMacroB[a,b,c,1,2,3]+\\
\myMacroB[a,b,c,1,2,3]

4. \verb+\myMacroB[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]+\\
\myMacroB[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not part of the question, but there are a few things that should be 'tidied up' here for `expl3` 'compliance': do you details? BTW, is there a reason that `\myMacroA/B` don't take the list as a mandatory argument and don't have the 'truly' optional argument first?

Comment: @JosephWright the list could be a mandatory variable of course in which case it makes sense to put the optional delimiter out front. For better or worse, whenever I can I like to keep all arguments optional and have my macros do something completely standard or typical if written down without any arguments at all. In this case I might have specified something like {O{a,b,c}O{,}}.

Comment: Can you quickly explain what the purpose is for the two different macros `\myMacroA` and `\myMacroB`? Both split a string into its parts, don't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a variant of `\seq_set_split:Nnn` that uses the value of `\sep_tl`, not the literal `\sep_tl` -- which is not the delimiter there.

With other words: `\seq_set_split:NVn`, which does not exist yet but can be generated with

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn}
```

This `\seq_set_split:NVn` will now use the **V**alue of `\sep_tl` (or any other variable that can be used with an `V` type.

Here is the shortened code, clearified, shortened, using the `expl3` naming syntax, but first some comments:

- `\seq_clear:N` isn't necessary if `\seq_set_split` is used -- that command clears the sequence anyway
- `\seq_use:Nn` is much easier than glueing things together with some `\tl_map_inline` etc. loop.
- There are two scratch variables ('registers') for almost any `expl3` datatype, that can be used for storing intermediate data, such as `\l_tmpa_tl` and `\l_tmpb_tl` or `\l_tmpa_seq` etc.

---

```
\documentclass{article}% Don't use minimal!
%   --------------------
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%   --------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_Args_seq
\tl_new:N \l_neuwirth_sep_tl
%   --------------------

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn}

\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroA{O{}O{,}}{\neuwirth_myMacroA:nn {#1}{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroB{O{}O{,}}{\neuwirth_myMacroB:nn {#1}{#2}}


\cs_new:Npn \neuwirth_myMacroA:nn #1 #2
  {
    %\seq_clear:N \l_neuwirth_Args_seq
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_neuwirth_Args_seq #2 {#1}
    \myShowArgs{\l_neuwirth_Args_seq}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \neuwirth_myMacroB:nn #1 #2
  {
    %\seq_clear:N \l_neuwirth_Args_seq% Not necessary since \seq_set_split clears the seq-variable
    \tl_set:Nn \l_neuwirth_sep_tl {#2}
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l_neuwirth_Args_seq \l_neuwirth_sep_tl {#1}
    \neuwirth_myShowArgs{\l_neuwirth_Args_seq}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \neuwirth_myShowArgs #1 {%
  \seq_use:Nn #1 {\c_space_token}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
1. \verb+\myMacroA[a,b,c,1,2,3]+\\
\myMacroA[a,b,c,1,2,3]

2. \verb+\myMacroA[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]+\\
\myMacroA[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]

3. \verb+\myMacroB[a,b,c,1,2,3]+\\
\myMacroB[a,b,c,1,2,3]

4. \verb+\myMacroB[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]+\\
\myMacroB[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't help myself but I feel that experienced users shouldn't post bad code. At least, the mistakes shall be pointed out...

Comment: @yo': Solution first, then improvement ;-)

Comment: Much nicer. Just two things: **(1)** `\myMacroA_Main:nn` shall be `\neuwirth_myMacroA:nn` and similar for `B`. **(2)** Both shall be `\cs_new_protected` rather than `\cs_new`.

Comment: @yo': Sighhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: Nobody has ever said expl3 compliance is easy.

Comment: @yo' It's not hard either.

Comment: `\myShowArgs` also doesn't comply with expl3 syntax. And while we're at it: using braces with an N-type argument also is wrong. (Sorry Christian!)

Comment: @clemens: I missed the `{}` apparently. Apart from using `_protected` anything I cleared the rest.

Comment: One more little thing: `\neuwirth_myShowArgs{\l_neuwirth_Args_seq}` shall become `\neuwirth_myShowArgs:N \l_neuwirth_Args_seq` and `\cs_new:Npn \neuwirth_myShowArgs #1` shall become `\cs_new:Npn \neuwirth_myShowArgs:N #1`.

Answer (score 9):

You have several errors in your code. Comments marked `%%%` refer either to the code at the left or to the code that follows

```
\documentclass{article}
%   --------------------
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%   --------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
%%% the names are not compliant
\seq_new:N \Args_seq
\int_new:N \ItemCount_int
\int_new:N \index_i
\tl_new:N \aux_tl
\tl_new:N \sep_tl
%   --------------------
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn}
%%% one of the arguments ought to be mandatory
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroA{O{}O{,}}{\myMacroA_Main:nn {#1}{#2}}
%%% the name is not compliant
\cs_new:Npn \myMacroA_Main:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_clear:N \Args_seq
    \seq_set_split:Nnn {\Args_seq} #2 {#1}
    \myShowArgs{\Args_seq}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroB{O{}O{,}}{\myMacroB_Main:nn {#1}{#2}}

%%% the name is not compliant; the function should be protected
\cs_new:Npn \myMacroB_Main:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_clear:N \Args_seq %%% useless
    \tl_set:Nn \sep_tl {#2}
    \seq_set_split:NVn \Args_seq \sep_tl {#1}  %does not accept the delimiter as a _tl variable.
    \myShowArgs{\Args_seq} %%% the call is not compliant
  }
%%% the name is not compliant and the code below can be shortened
\cs_new:Npn \myShowArgs #1
  {
    \tl_clear:N \aux_tl    
    \int_set:Nn \ItemCount_int {\seq_count:N #1}
    \int_set:Nn \index_i {1}
    \int_do_until:nNnn \index_i > \ItemCount_int
      {
        \tl_set:Nx \aux_tl {\seq_item:Nn #1 {\index_i}}
        \tl_use:N \aux_tl \text{~}
        \int_incr:N \index_i
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
1. \verb+\myMacroA[a,b,c,1,2,3]+\\
\myMacroA[a,b,c,1,2,3]

2. \verb+\myMacroA[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]+\\
\myMacroA[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]

3. \verb+\myMacroB[a,b,c,1,2,3]+\\
\myMacroB[a,b,c,1,2,3]

4. \verb+\myMacroB[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]+\\
\myMacroB[1;2;3;a;b;c][;]
\end{document}
```

Now, let's look at compliant and simplified code. I used `rn` as your personal prefix.

1. The main argument to `\myMacroA` and `\myMacroB` ought to be mandatory
2. Function where variables are set should be `protected`.
3. If an argument to a function is supposed to be a variable, then the argument type should be `N`
4. With `\seq_use:Nn` the code for showing the sequence items can be simplified; if instead you want to do something to each item, use `\seq_map_inline:Nn` or `\seq_map_function:NN`
5. When you're using `\seq_set_split:Nnn` (or the variant) you don't need to clear the variable beforehand; the same for `\tl_set:Nn`

```
\documentclass{article}
%   --------------------
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%   --------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
\seq_new:N \l_rn_args_seq
\tl_new:N \l_rn_sep_tl
%   --------------------
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn}
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroA{O{,}m}
  {
    \rn_MacroA_Main:nn {#1}{#2}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \rn_MacroA_Main:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_rn_args_seq {#1} {#2}
    \rn_ShowArgs:N \l_rn_args_seq
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\myMacroB{O{,}m}
  {
    \rn_MacroB_Main:nn {#1}{#2}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \rn_MacroB_Main:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_sep_tl {#1}
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l_rn_args_seq \l_rn_sep_tl {#2}
    \rn_ShowArgs:N \l_rn_args_seq
  }
\cs_new:Npn \rn_ShowArgs:N #1
  {
   \seq_use:Nn #1 { ~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
1. \verb+\myMacroA{a,b,c,1,2,3}+\\
\myMacroA{a,b,c,1,2,3}

2. \verb+\myMacroA[;]{1;2;3;a;b;c}+\\
\myMacroA[;]{1;2;3;a;b;c}

3. \verb+\myMacroB{a,b,c,1,2,3}+\\
\myMacroB{a,b,c,1,2,3}

4. \verb+\myMacroB[;]{1;2;3;a;b;c}+\\
\myMacroB[;]{1;2;3;a;b;c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd be tempted to make the variables internal as well ... otherwise very nice :-)

Comment: @JosephWright That adds a level of complexity that seemed not relevant for illustrating the main rules.